# Serialization of generic type information scala?

Tags: java, scala, generics, serialization

I'm building a DSL in scala with a number of expressions and operators that I'd like to know about their own type. For example:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait Expression[T] {
    def evaluate: T
    def evalType: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Type  // represents T
}
```

I'd like to use the type information for a variety of purposes (e.g. printing the types of Expressions, filtering expression by their result type, and casting collections of Expression[_] to some type or another. I can do this (below), but can't seem to keep both the generic type information AND have the property that the type information is serializable.

I can make classes aware of their type parameter like so:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

case class TypeAware[T:TypeTag](c:Type=null) {
  val typ:Type = if (c==null) typeOf[T] else c
}  

class RelectionUtilTest {

  @Test
  def serializeTypeTest(): Unit = {
    val obj = TypeAware[Seq[Int]]()
    println(obj.typ) // Seq[Int]
    val copy = SerializationUtil.copyBySerialization(obj)  // via ObjectOutputStream -> ObjectInputStream
    println(copy.typ)
  }
}
```

... but the scala's Type field is not Serializable.

Or I can make the class aware of the Class[_] of T

```
case class ClassAware[T:TypeTag](c:Class[_]=null) {
  val clz:Class[_] = if (c==null) runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader).runtimeClass(typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass) else c
}

class RelectionUtilTest {

  @Test
  def serializeTypeTest(): Unit = {
    val obj = ClassAware[Seq[Int]]()
    println(obj.typ) // Seq[_]
    val copy = SerializationUtil.copyBySerialization(obj)
    println(copy.typ)
  }
}
```

but a java Class[_] is type-erased :-(

So, how can I serialize the generic type information in scala?

UPDATE: Serializing Java's ParameterizedType seems like a solution, but [I don't see how to convert java ParameterizedType `<->` scala Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256500/get-parameterizedtype-from-scalas-type).